# SSL certificate for wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, openssl, certbot

I migrated **my Wordpress** website from Local by Flywheel to my personnal VM. I ran by myself web, php, mysql and smtp servers. The site is now installed but I have problem with the **SSL certificate**. I tried to generate it with **openssl and certbot**. It appears to be correctly installed but when I connect to my website with https, I got this message **"secure connection failed, this could be a problem with the server's configuration"**. I tried to use *Simple SSL plugin* but it doesn't work neither. Do you have an idea of the origin of the problem ?

I have also make a mistake, I redirected http to https and now I can't access to the administration interface of my website.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed this issue by deleting certbot certificate, the plugin *Really Simple SSL* and giving 755 permission to the file .htacess. Only openssl certificate remains.